# GitHub: Not getting contribution points

Tags: git, github

On GitHub I cloned friend's repository to my desktop and I actively work in it. I am able to use all of the standard GitHub functions with this repository. I don't have any issues committing, branching or pushing to his repository on GitHub.

The issue is that when I push to his repository GitHub says that I authored the changes with my commit message, but I don't get any contribution points on my profile.

When I first found this issue I followed [these instructions](https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git#email) to change my user name and email on my laptop to match my information of GitHub. Now instead of the repo saying it was authored by my name it says it was authored by my username. I ran the following commands in my terminal to make those changes.

```
git config --global user.name "YOUR NAME"
git config --global user.email "YOUR EMAIL ADDRESS"
```

Please note that his repo is private. I can confirm that my local copy of his repo is a clone and not my own fork. Any insight would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: The contribution graph takes some time to update. Also, all commits from before you changed your `user.email` won't be recognized unless you add the old `user.email` to your GitHub profile as well.

Comment: @chris do you know how long it takes for contributions to register?

Comment: I don't know, but it's not instantaneous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking into this further I found that my "profile email," which is your profile facing email was correct, but under settings -> emails, my address associated with my account was incorrect. I fixed it, set the correct email as my default email and contacted GitHub support to get my contribution points that were missing.